# Precision Problem Between Java and Sql Server when Data Size is big

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I have a Java application that calculates the sum of Data using the type `Double`, and an Sql query that Calculates the sum using `Float`type.

To verify the data we do a sum check between another app using Java and our Sql Database. And we have a tolerance of 2 numbers difference.

This solution always worked for me and was able to get the same sum in both sides.

Lately it stopped working and started returning differences of thousands.Specificly when it's tested on a volumenous chunk of data ( Talking about  sum result of 100billions).

Not sure if the volumetry has any impact on the precisions problem, but I would like a hand of help to understand the problem behind this precision problem, and if there is anyway I can make it work in all cases no matter how small or big the data is.

The choise of the Java Type and Sql Type was taken based on the mapping between these two langages : [Link Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/language-extensions/how-to/java-to-sql-data-types?view=sql-server-ver16). ( Also It was Tested and gave the expected results).

My Java Code is smthg similar to this :

```
sumPrice += Double.valueOf(price);
```

My Sql Sum Query :

```
 select sum(CONVERT(float, price)) ) from table where 'filter only Numeric values'
```

The price column is a varchar type for some specifications reasons.

Many Thanks

I tried using Decimal(38,4) but had the precision problem still.

For example with the last chunky data , in java we have a total : `5 555 555 555 555.55` but in sql we get `5 555 555 522 222.22`.

Before this problem, it will normally return in java `5 555 555 555 555.55` and in sql `5 555 555 555 522.22` ( 2 digit difference).

Comment: Ignoring for a moment that `float` and `real` are [approximate-number data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql), in other words "lossy", why would you use IBM Informix documentation to infer behaviors about Microsoft SQL Server? Comparing the [Informix](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=types-floatn#ids_sqr_118) and [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql) documentation shows that their `float` types have different precision.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thank you for pointing this out. The link was fixed.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning do you have any idea what will be better to use for more precision ? and how could you explain than Float(sql) and Double (java) worked before but once the data got chunkier we noticed bigger diffrences. Thank you in advance

Comment: `decimal(38, 9)` maybe?

Comment: The solution is to use BigDecimal type in Java.

Comment: Agree with @Mar-Z, bigdecimal is the "only" way

Comment: @Mar-Z , Thank you so much. BigDecimal in Java, and its equivelent in sql is Decimal ?

Comment: @siggemannen Thanks! Its equivalent in Sql will be Decimal(38,9)  ? correct me please if I am wrong

Comment: I believe it can hold most numbers :) you specify precision and you're good to go

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `BigDecimal` type in Java. It is equivalent to database DECIMAL and/or NUMBER and should be mapped correctly by JDBC driver. You can specify precision and scale for `BigDecimal`. Similar to the database types. And specify how to round the results. `BigDecimal` is **the** datatype for financial applications like banking where any loss of accuracy in calculations is unacceptable.

Comment: This is the general solution for most if not all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Java Float and Double are not exact types. BigInteger or BigDecimal can perform arithmetic computations with arbitrary precision and can be a great solution.

Now, if your apps need to add and subtract values with two decimal places, sometimes it's easy to get them multiplied by 100 as a `long`. Then it's easy to add and subtract longs -- **without losing any precision**. When saving back to the database, just divide by 100.

Comment: Very Intersting! Thank you for sharing. I will try your solution and the others and see what will work best.